# How do I attach a file using qmail on a Solaris server?

Tags: database, email, attachment, qmail

Specifically, I would like to attach multiple files to an outgoing email using tcl and qmail on a solaris server.

Answer (score 0):

qmail is an MTA so dont expect qmail to attach something by itself.
Also attaching an attachment in the mail body has to be as per the rfc. I know of php which has mime_parser functions which automatically creates the mime body for attachment mails.

If you want you can have your own function or may be some open source code, i know of altermime which can add remove attachments, disclaimers from the mail body.

Make sure to have this code place before qmail-queue is called.